# PersistentVolumeClaim is deleted but I can see pvc provisioning failed logs sitll in kube-controller-manager

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a static provisioning storageClass and then create PVC

Now I have deleted the PVC and SC but I still can see some failed logs from  kube-controller-manager:

```sh
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ k delete pvc task-pv-claim2  
Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "task-pv-claim2" not found
```

Error logs from kube-controller-manager:

```sh
E0305 10:23:53.767808       1 pv_controller.go:1336] error finding provisioning plugin for claim default/task-pv-claim2: storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found
I0305 10:23:53.767845       1 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"task-pv-claim2", UID:"4876b753-2c59-4fc4-b618-d56f3ae7ae99", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1810421", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found
E0305 10:24:08.768023       1 pv_controller.go:1336] error finding provisioning plugin for claim default/task-pv-claim2: storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found
I0305 10:24:08.768134       1 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"task-pv-claim2", UID:"4876b753-2c59-4fc4-b618-d56f3ae7ae99", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1810421", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found
E0305 10:24:23.768267       1 pv_controller.go:1336] error finding provisioning plugin for claim default/task-pv-claim2: storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found
I0305 10:24:23.768453       1 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"task-pv-claim2", UID:"4876b753-2c59-4fc4-b618-d56f3ae7ae99", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1810421", FieldPath:"^C
```

Does someone know how to do troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are using the PVC in a workload. Check your deployments, statefulsets, daemonsets, pods, etc

```
kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces
kubectl get ds --all-namespaces
kubectl get sts --all-namespaces
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

Then if you see one check the manifests:

```
kubectl get <resource> <resource-name> -o=yaml
```

Look for `PersistentVolumeClaim` ️